# How to reference attached images from html email body in CRM2011

Tags: email, attachment, mime, dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to create an email with an embedded image from within a CRM2011 plug-in.
So the plan is to create an email entity, add an attachment entity to it and include an image element like the following in the email html body:

```
<img src="cid:image001.png@01CBDDB1.BACB59F0" />
```

The problem is that I do not know how the content-id is generated by CRM2011.

The first part (`image001.png`) is obviously the file name of the attachment. But where does the other part (`@01CBDDB1.BACB59F0`) come from? Is there a way to derrive this part based on the fields of the attachment entity?

Cheers,
Nang.

Comment: It seems like this is not possible. Reason: Emails are not sent by CRM2011 directly, but by an external component like CRM for Outlook, CRM Email Router or a 3rd party tool. These external components retrieve the emails to be sent as XML representations of CRM entities. It is the job of the external component now to serialize the email body and attachments, and part of this is to create mime parts including content-ids. So there is no chance to know the content-ids in a CRM plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the raw MIME that is delivered to the email client, when the attachments are added to the email by the email router there is no ContentID specified and I can't see anyway of adding one through the SDK ActivityMimeAttachment.

The only alternative I can think of, if your writing server code, is to send the email directly to your SMTP server, that way you can add your content id for your attachments and reference them in the image.  You could use OpenPop to relay the message.

Another alternative I've tried is to embed the image as data in the img tag as base64encoded.  While this works, it seems that Outlook for the mac and windows does not render the image correctly when view the message.  If you view click the view message in browser, html message displayed correctly in the browser.  But that's not a lot of use. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Comment: Seems that mail systems remove base64 encoded images from message body